# How can I asynchronously render a large Component in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a large Component which renders after `onPress` event, but I want to display some 'loading...' until the Component is ready to render.

Assume I have imported the large component

```
import LargeComponent from '../components/LargeComponent'
```

```
state={
   showComponent: false
}
```

When I press the button, it gets stuck for 1 to 2 seconds and then renders the component
so, I want to asynchronously render the component and I want to show some loading
until the component is ready to render

```
<Button onPress={this.pressHandler} title='show component'/>

{this.state.showComponent ? <LargeComponent/> : null}
```

```
pressHandler = () => {
  this.setState({   
    showComponent :true
  })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.lazy()` takes a function as its argument that must return a promise by calling import() to load the component. The returned Promise resolves to a module with a default export containing the React component. You can also create a HOC for it and resuse it..

Here is what using `React.lazy()` looks like:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const LazyLargeComponent = React.lazy(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5 * 1000)).then(
    () => import("../components/LargeComponent")
  );
});

export default function LargeComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div}>
          <LazyLargeComponent />
        </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more info check [react-api reactlazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy)

Thanks.

Comment: the large component i have is in local not on internet so can i use it there ?

Answer (score 1):

In `pressHandler` sleep for 2-3 seconds before you set the state.

Since you cannot post the component's code, I will not write the full code, but this is the general idea:

- Initialize `this.state.showComponent` to false and `this.state.isLoading` to false
- When the button is pressed, set `this.state.isLoading` to true. This will cause `render()` to display a spinner/loading message
- When the sleep is over, set `this.state.isLoading` to false and `this.state.showComponent` to true

BTW, the sleep can be implemented as following:

```
pressHandler = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, showComponent: true }); 
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: is there any way that i can show loading... before it renders ?